# How to model cassandra columnfamily

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

Is the below select queries are possible for the columnfamily I have defined, because I am getting a bad request error. How should I Model my columnfamily to get the correct results.

`CREATE TABLE recordhistory (
  userid bigint,
  objectid bigint,
  operation text,
  record_link_id bigint,
  time timestamp,
  username text,
  value map<bigint, text>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((userid, objectid), operation, record_link_id, time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (operation ASC, record_link_id ASC, time DESC)`

Select Query:

```
SELECT * FROM recordhistory WHERE userid=439035 AND objectid=20011009 AND operation='update' AND time>=1389205800000 AND time<=1402338600000 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY column "time" cannot be restricted (preceding column "record_link_id" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)

```
SELECT * FROM recordhistory WHERE userid=439035 AND objectid=20011009 AND record_link_id=20011063 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY column "record_link_id" cannot be restricted (preceding column "operation" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY part to\_id cannot be restricted" when trying to select using where condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989708/bad-request-primary-key-part-to-id-cannot-be-restricted-when-trying-to-select)

Comment: Actually here I am having partition key in query and trying to use ALLOW FILTERING by skipping some of clustering columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table recordhistory (
userid bigint,
objectid bigint,
operation text,
record_link_id bigint,
time timestamp,
username text,
value map<bigint, text>,
PRIMARY KEY ((userid, objectid), time, operation, record_link_id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC, operation ASC, record_link_id ASC);

select * from recordhistory where userid=12346 AND objectid=45646 and time >=1389205800000 and time <1402338700000 ALLOW FILTERING;

 userid | objectid | time                     | operation | record_link_id | username | value
--------+----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------------+----------+-------
  12346 |    45646 | 2014-06-09 11:30:00-0700 |     myop4 |          78946 |    name3 |  null
  12346 |    45646 | 2014-01-08 10:30:00-0800 | myop99999 |         999999 |    name3 |  null
```

Comment: thank you for answer, if I create an index on record_link_id and i ll query like select * from recordhistory where userid = 12346 and objectid = 45646 and record_link_id = 78946; in this query cassandra will touch all nodes?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Cassandra will not let you perform such a potentially expensive query that might bring down the system. To do a range query, the data has to be in contiguous order on the disk. So, if you make Time the first clustering column, you can query by Time range.